# How to kill/stop telerik report while it is being generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a Telerik ReportViewer and a button. Here is the code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Report = (Telerik.Reporting.Report)session["TelerikReportObject"];
            ReportViewer1.DataBind();
        }

    protected void ButtonKillThenNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here I need some mechanism to kill the Report (if it is still being generated) so I can immediately navigate to another page without a delay.
        // Now with my current code, a very noticeable delay exists before executing the redirection in the following line of code

        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
```

If there is no way to kill the report, can I call `ReportViewer1.Dispose()`along with `Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")`as an **asynchronous** operation? If I can accomplish that, I will be able to navigate to my page immediately without delay while the report will be disposed whenever he wants.

Check the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One very simple option might be to just have a normal html link to `Home.aspx` on the page.  That should bring the user's browser to Home.aspx and close its connection waiting for the report.  It probably won't cancel the report generation (that will probably continue until finished, then close the process handling the page).  But this has the operation you'd want from the user perspective, and only wastes resources as long as a normal report would.

Other than that, look into the `ReportViewer1.RefreshReportCommand` command.  I am guessing here, but you might be able to reconfigure the ReportViewer with zero data, then call the refresh method which *might* cancel the existing process and generate the zero data report very quickly, then finish.

With my limited experience with Telerik Reporting I don't believe they have it designed for async operations for the most part.